# 'Install' a private Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google Spreadsheet, you can go to Tools --> Script Gallery and then 'install' any of the public scripts from the gallery.

Is it possible to similarly 'install' a script that is not part of the Script Gallery. Or should I be filing an enhancement request for the same ?

The problem at hand is a similar script is required across multiple spreadsheets. One option is to make use of libraries, but that will again require writing or atleast copy-pasting the skeleton code that uses the library in each of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should fill an enhancement request on the issue tracker (and I'll be happy to stare it).

For now on, if you don't want to share your script publicly but you need an easy install for your users (they should see no code), you can:

- create a spreadsheet template in the Google Docs template gallery
- create a Chrome Web App and share it with a specific group
- put your script in a Google Sites and add a UI to let the user choose on which spreadsheet the script should be triggered.

Comment: Thanks, Romain. I've opened Issue 1599 ( http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1599 )

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install your private library by using its ID

You can find the ID of your library under Tools-Script Editor->File->Project Properties->Info->Project Key

Comment: I am aware of the Libraries facility as I mentioned in my question itself. Even when I use a library, I still need to write (or copy-paste) code that calls the library in each spreadsheet. The install feature of scripts in the gallery is very convenient - no code is necessary at all. I'm wondering if it is possible to do this 'install' for scripts not in the gallery

Comment: @Srik for security reasons you have to define your methods name and exact behavior. The definition of this API is usually a very small part of the implementation code, which you can "install" as described above. You can "install" your private library and write 3 lines that call it.